# Importing modules with forRoot()

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I am going through the [example of Angular2 Material](https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) and I see that all Material modules are imported in the root module using the `forRoot()` method. So in my app I do the same.

Now I need to use some Material components within other Shared modules, which means that I need to import the related Material packages in my Shared module. I am not clear whether I need to use the `forRoot()` method also while importing them in the Shared module.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`forRoot` is only used for the main app module. It is a convention used so that only the app module gets application/singleton providers. This is to avoid providers that are supposed to be singletons, being created more than once for the application. For example

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ SomeDirective ],
  exports: [ SomeDirective ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ AuthProvider ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here we should only call `forRoot` while importing into the app module, so that it can create the `AuthProvider` only once as a singleton. All other modules that need the `SharedModule` should simply import `ShareModule` so that it can use the `SharedDirective`.

So calling `forRoot` in the app module gets you everything provided by that module (and conventionally the providers that come with calling `forRoot`) into the app module. So all the components declared in your app module have access to to everything from that module.

But everything in the `declarations` (this include components, directives, and pipes) isn't inherited by any sub-modules. So we still need to import the module into any other module we need it in.

Your question seems to be specifically about your `ShareModule`. For this module, you should not use `forRoot`, for reasons I mentioned above. You should just `exports` the MD module(s). You only use `imports` if some component declared in that `SharedModule` actually requires any MD modules. For example, if you have a component that uses the MD button, and that component is a shared component that you declare in the `SharedModule`. In this case you should `imports` and `exports`. But if there are no such components, you only need to `exports`. This provides the MD module(s) to whatever module you import the `SharedModule` into.