# Can lazy-loaded modules share the same instance of a service provided by their parent?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've just run into a problem with a lazy-loaded module where parent and child module both require the same service but create an instance each. The declaration is identical for both, that is

```
import { MyService } from './my.service';
...
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [
      MyService,
      ...
   ]
});
```

and here's the routing setup

```
export parentRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: ':id', component: ParentComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: ParentDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'child', loadChildren: 'app/child.module#ChildModule' },
      ...
   ]}
];
```

which, of course, is then imported in the parent module as

```
RouterModule.forChild(parentRoutes)
```

How do I go about this if I wanted to share the same service instance?

Comment: You want single instance for whole application or for a particular featureModule?

Comment: For the whole application. Actually, the parent module mentioned above is the root module (`AppModule`).

Comment: Okay Then whats the problem with this?

Comment: It's instantiated twice, once from the root module and once from the child module. I put a `console.log` in the service's constructor and I got 2 lines, tracked those calls down and one is from `AppComponent` and one from the 'root' component of the child module.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Using a `forRoot`, as mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665993/2587435), is what you need probably. The problem it's meant to solve, is directly related to the problem you are experiencing with lazy loaded modules getting their own service.

It's explained here in [Configure core services with `forRoot`](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot), but that section doesn't explain about the lazy-loading issue. That is explained with a little warning at the end of [Shared Modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module)

> Do not specify app-wide singleton `providers` in a shared module. A lazy loaded module that imports that shared module will make its own copy of the service.

```
@NgModule({})
class SharedModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ MyService ]
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  import: [ SharedModule.forRoot() ]
})
class AppModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule ]
})
class LazyLoadedModule {}
```

This makes sure that the lazy loaded module doesn't get the service. But whether or not the module is lazy loaded or not, this is the pattern that is recommended for app-wide services. Though it should be noted that if you don't have any lazy loaded module, not using the `forRoot` patter, and just importing `SharedModule`, it will only be one instance of the service. But this pattern should still recommended to be followed.

---

#### UPDATE

I guess I jumped to quick on answering without fully looking at the question. In the question, there *is* no mention of any shared module. It seems the OP is simply trying to add the service to the `@NgModule.providers` in both the app module and the lazy loaded child module.

In this case, simply remove the service from the child module `providers`. It is not needed. The one added in the app module is enough for the child to be used.

Just remember that `providers` are app wide (except in the problem case this post is about), while `declarations` are not.

Comment: Thing is, this service provides the theme (which colors to use) for the whole application, and the current settings are stored in a cookie, which is loaded at application start. If I go to settings in my app, the new color settings are applied by notifying the `ThemeManager` and picked up by any component that listens to the `theme` observable. Having multiple instances of that service would defy its purpose.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my answer. The solution to the problem is to _not_ add the service to `@NgModule.providers`, but to add it in a `forRoot`. In the AppModule, import it by calling `TheModule.forRoot()`, and when you import to other modules, just import `TheModule`

Comment: Looking at your example again, it doesn't appear you had any mention of a shared module. In this case simply _don't include_ the service in the child module. It will still be able to use the one provided by the app module.

Comment: This doesn’t work, each module still creates its own instance.

Answer (score 17):

This should work but still I would suggest you to go with **SharedModule** concept which contains **common** *services,pipes,directives and components*.

**Shared/SharedModule**

```
import { NgModule,ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';

import { MyService } from './my.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [ CommonModule ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ MyService ]                       //<<<====here
    };
  }
}
```

**AppModule**

```
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';
...
@NgModule({
   imports:[ BrowserModule,SharedModule.forRoot()],  //<<<====here
   providers: []
});
```

Comment: A shared module contains only common directives, components and pipes, but NOT services. Services are related to features and in most cases not to be placed in a shared module. If you have to share a service, use the `forRoot()` approach, described in the angular docs.

Comment: This worked for me, I fully moved files in barrel and then started getting error, but after reordering export most dependency injection resolved and last one was remain, that was in shared module , inside directive not able to resolve injection but doing above way, it solved my problem, so basically it loaded shared module lazily. I am using Angular CLI 1.2.6 and Angular 4.3.2. Thanks  @micronyks

Comment: You first said *This should work but still I would suggest you to go with SharedModule*. But the code you wrote after that seems to be the `sharedModule` does not it?

Comment: What about shared pipes, and directive?

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate layout module with a service, this service needed to work on other feature modules, using lazy load

I was able to solve the problem by exporting the service, straight from the layout module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [...],
    exports: [...],
})
export class LayoutModule {
    ...
}

export { LayoutService }
```