# How to use OverlayModule (angular2-material) in Angular2 App

Tags: angular, angular2-material

**NOTE : I don't use Angular-Cli**

**OverlayModule** seems to be required for other angular2-material components.

> zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./AppComponent class
>   AppComponent - inline template:2:2 caused by: No provider for Overlay!
>   ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

I have installed all packages from angular2-material.

**sytemjs.config.js**

```
 map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'dist',
      ...
      ...
      '@angular2-material/core': 'npm:@angular2-material/core/core.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/button': 'npm:@angular2-material/button/button.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/menu': 'npm:@angular2-material/menu/menu.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/icon': 'npm:@angular2-material/icon/icon.umd.js',
      _____________________________________________________________________
      /*>>>>>   DO I NEED TO MAP ANYTHING FOR OVERLAY HERE?  <<<<<< */
      ______________________________________________________________________
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
```

I'm using **sharedModule** for angular2-material components So that they will be available everywhere.

**shared.module.ts**

```
import {MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import {MdIconModule} from '@angular2-material/icon';
import {MdMenuModule} from '@angular2-material/menu';
import {MdIconRegistry} from '@angular2-material/icon';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [ CommonModule,MdButtonModule,MdMenuModule,MdIconModule],
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ MdIconRegistry ]  //>>>>> DO I NEED TO ADD ANYTHING HERE ??
    };
  }
}
```

**App.Module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,SharedModule.forRoot()],  
  ...
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
   <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>

<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item> Refresh </button>
    <button md-menu-item> Settings </button>
    <button md-menu-item> Help </button>
    <button md-menu-item disabled> Sign Out </button>
</md-menu>
<button md-raised-button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Updated my question with HTML.

Comment: https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts here they import `OverlayModule` like : `import {OverlayModule} from '@angular2-material/core/overlay/overlay-directives';` If I try to do the same thing in sharedModule , it throws error like : `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/core/core.umd.js/overlay/overlay-directives 404 (Not Found)`. I fell like I need to `map something` in `systemjs.config.js` but lately found that OverlayModule doesn't have `umd.js` So can't map anything in system file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options:

- 1) Try to import `OverlayModule` in your shared module as shown below:

**shared.module.ts**

```
import {OverlayModule } from '@angular2-material/core';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, OverlayModule.forRoot() ], <== here
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [ CommonModule,MdButtonModule,MdMenuModule,MdIconModule],
})
export class SharedModule {
```

- 2) you can import it in main module
- 3) or use the following:

**shared.module.ts**

```
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: SharedModule,
      [ MdIconRegistry,  MdMenuModule.forRoot().providers ]
  };
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/sA24hFGNRSr2pXcdpCOe?p=preview)**

- 4) Or this way:

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, MdMenuModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [ CommonModule,MdButtonModule,MdMenuModule,MdIconModule],
})
```

- 5) just add providers to your SharedModule

**shared.module.ts**

```
 import {OVERLAY_PROVIDERS } from '@angular2-material/core';
 return {
   ngModule: SharedModule,
   providers: [ MdIconRegistry,  OVERLAY_PROVIDERS ]
 };
```

---

`forRoot()` always return ModuleWithProviders object:

```
export interface ModuleWithProviders {
  ngModule: Type<any>;
  providers?: Provider[];
}

export class MdMenuModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MdMenuModule,
      providers: OVERLAY_PROVIDERS,
    };
  }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.8/src/lib/menu/menu.ts#L21

Comment: Just awesome. But why `import {OverlayModule } from '@angular2-material/core';` i don't get it.

Comment: I tried to give you +2 but I can't :(. I need explanation on this.

Comment: How do you know  `MdMenuModule.forRoot().providers` ? any document or something?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding to the providers or calling the forRoot in the shared module imports, for reasons [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39672927/2587435)

Comment: @micronyks i guess `MdMenuModule.forRoot().providers` is the same as if you just import `OVERLAY_PROVIDERS` in put in providers

Comment: but why import `{OverlayModule } from '@angular2-material/core';`?

Comment: because it is public api https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.8/src/lib/core/core.ts#L35 and if you're using import from `core/overlay/overlay-directives` and bundle then it won't work

Comment: the same thing happens where you use something like this `import {class} from @angular/core/src/..` and load `@angulat/core` as `umd.js`

Comment: With this config your import `'@angular2-material/core/overlay/overlay-directives` will work https://gist.github.com/alexzuza/faf709f877c9adcc5e68ae6efbea403b

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677663/2587435).

The first thing to mention is that `forRoot()` should not be imported into shared modules, for reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672816/can-lazy-loaded-modules-share-the-same-instance-of-a-service-provided-by-their-p/39672927#39672927). Now should the providers from them be extracted out to add the shared modules `@NgModule.providers`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SomeModule.forRoot() ],
  providers: [ SomeModule.forRoot().providers ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Don't do either of those. Not in a shared module. Below is OK, though I don't think it's meant to be used this way

```
@NgModule({})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ SomeModule.forRoot().providers ]
    }
  }
}
```

Like I said it's OK, it'll work, but it just *looks* weird. Maybe a more elegant solution is the one provided by Material themselves. It you look at snapshot (as of now - will be in next release), you will see where they made a [module that consolidated all the MD modules](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/module.ts). Maybe just do what they are doing, but instead of adding all the modules, just add the ones you use

```
const MATERIAL_MODULES = [
  MdButtonModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdMenuModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MdButtonModule.forRoot(),
    MdIconModule.forRoot(),
    MdMenuModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: MATERIAL_MODULES
})
export class MaterialRootModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: MATERIAL_MODULES,
  exports: MATERIAL_MODULES
})
export class MaterialModule {
  static forRoot() {
    ngModule: MaterialRootModule
  }
}
```

And in your shared module just

```
exports: [ MaterialModule ]
```

and in the app module

```
imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot() ]
```

Style-wise, I think I would probably go this route.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.I offered to add `SomeModule.forRoot().providers` within forRoot method. With the first statement I agree.