# How to access child's child in angular 2+?

Tags: angular, parent-child

How would someone access a component of a childs child.

`parent > child > interesting child`

I used `ViewChild` and it shows the child and its child, but I cannot access childs child public attributes.

`this.list - returns ok`

`this.list.infinityList returns undefined`

Why?

[image]

Comment: Should probably be using a service for that sort of thing

Comment: Can you give me an example, because the idea is: Change a property on data and watch for the change on child, but cannot do this easily with angular 2 as in angular 1. I dont want to use the subject, as I need to send the whole modified object, I just want to modify one property and have the child to act on the change.

Comment: Check out my example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/ The plunker is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

Comment: As stated by @Z.Bagley you could go with **Shared Service** If you have a Lazy Loaded Module you need to follow an approach,
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html

Eg: The problem with shared service in Lazy loaded module:
https://plnkr.co/edit/L2ypUQZiltSPXnLlxBoa?p=preview

https://plnkr.co/edit/kqat7k4YhLSDKrjr8x2f?p=preview

Comment: Post on StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672927
Have a look at this as well, https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#prevent-reimport-of-the-coremodule