# Approaches to services and components in Angular modules provided by libraries

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I thought I understood Angular modules, but am having trouble figuring out the best approach for structuring modules involving services and components to be provided by a library.

The library implements a `NotificationsComponent`, which depends on a `NotificationsService`, which needs to be a singleton since it persists notification information. The consumer wants to use the `NotificationsComponent` in various pages, some of which are inside an `AdminPagesModules`, and others are inside an `BookPagesModule`.

Let's say in the library I define a `NotificationsModule`, which "declares" and 
"exports" `NotificationsComponent`, and "provides" `NotificationsService`. Now if I import this module into both `AdminPagesModule` and `BookPagesModules` so pages in those modules can use `NotificationComponent`, I get separate instances of the `NotificationsService`, which won't work. On the other hand, if I import `NotificationsModule` in my `AppModule`, I succeed in making sure `NotificationsService` is a singleton used throughout the app, but I cannot see `NotificationsComponent` inside the components inside the individual feature modules such as `AdminPagesModule`.

I have seen a pattern where one module imports another module, then re-exports it. In this case, we would import `NotificationsModule` in `AppModule`, and then re-export it, then import `NotificationsModule` again in `AdminPagesModule`. In this case, will `NotificationsService` be a singleton across the app, as I want, yet `NotificationsComponent` still be available to components inside `AdminPagesModule`?

Or is there an approach to this problem involving the `SharedModule` pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Best to put singleton Services in a separate ts file and import/provide once and only once either in AppModule or SharedModule, not the component module (e.g. library).  Components declared in modules that are imported into AppModule will be available in **templates** throughout the app, and do not need to be re-declared or exported.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665993/3103979

Example of services provided in a SharedModule:

```
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        ...
        ApiService,
        Auth,
        ...
      ]
    };
  }
}
```