# Angular: forRoot/forChild methods usage?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-router

*I was surprised that there is no exact answer to question*:

What are methods **forRoot**/**forChild** made for?

For example in RouterModule:

```
Router.forRoot(routes)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498081/routermodule-forrootroutes-vs-routermodule-forchildroutes

Comment: yes, true, the question is more specific, but the answer is more general, thx!

Answer (score 8):

[RouterModule#forRoot](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forRoot)

> Creates a module with all the router providers and directives. It also
>   optionally sets up an application listener to perform an initial
>   navigation.

While [RouterModule#forChild](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forChild)

> Creates a module with all the router directives and a provider
>   registering routes.

The first is usually used to create the initial configuration for the Angular app and register the "base" routes while the second is usually used to configure "relative" routes.

Let's say we have an app with routes for:

1. User

   - Register
   - List
   - Delete
2. Company

   - Register
   - List
   - Delete

You could use the mentioned methods like this:

[**app-routing.module.ts**](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/client/src/app/app-routing.module.ts) <sup>(this is a "real" app, routes differ)</sup>

Where the base routes `user/` and `company/` are registered using `RouterModule#forRoot`

```
//...
const  routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#userModule'
    // this lazy loading is deprecated in favor of
    // loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule) }
  },
  // same deprecation applies here
  { path: 'company', loadChildren: './company/company.module#CompanyModule'},
  // same deprecation applies here
  { path: '**', loadChildren: './page-not-found/page-not-found.module#PageNotFoundModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
//...
```

[**user-routing.module.ts**](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/client/src/app/app-routing.module.ts) <sup>(this is a "real" app, routes differ)</sup>

And the relative routes to `user/` and `company/` are registered using `RouterModule#forChild`

```
//...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'list', component: UserComponent},
  { path: 'delete/:id', component: UserDeleteComponent},
  { path: 'register/:id', component: UserRegisterComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

//...
```

And the same would go on for the Company children routes.

Answer (score 3):

> **[forRoot()](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)**
>
> Creates a module with all the router providers and
> directives. It also optionally sets up an application listener to
> perform an initial navigation.
>
> **[forChild()](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)**
>
> Creates a module with all the router directives and a
> provider registering routes.

Use forRoot/forChild convention only for shared modules with providers that are going to be imported into both eager and lazy module modules

> [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

this one is a greate answer [What is purpose of using forRoot in NgModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524011/what-is-purpose-of-using-forroot-in-ngmodule) can give extra information about this topic

Comment: forChild() also used for lazy-loading modules etc

Comment: What is purpose of using forRoot in NgModule? answe has a good information  about this @TaranjitKang

Answer (score 1):

**Usage notes**

RouterModule can be imported multiple times: once per lazily-loaded bundle. Since the router deals with a global shared resource--location, we cannot have more than one router service active.

That is why there are **two ways** to create the module:

**1.** RouterModule.forRoot - forRoot creates a module that contains all the directives, the given routes, and the router service itself.

**2.** RouterModule.forChild - forChild creates a module that contains all the directives and the given routes, but does not include the router service..