# Angular forRoot and forChild

Tags: angular

I'm trying to understand Angular's `forRoot` and `forChild` static methods.

I have two questions.

#### 1) Are the following code snippets equivalent?

This:

```
// App Module
const routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

with this:

```
// App Module:
const routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
];

const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

// Dashboard Module:
const routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

#### 2) Do they work on the same object?

As I understand it, the `forRoot` method is the one that instantiates the router services. It adds the first route. The `forChild` than adds the second route to the same object.

Is that correct? Are `forRoot` and `forChild` working in the end on the same instance?

Comment: yes for the two questions

Comment: thx @julianobrasil

One more short question: I'm using Ionic in my app. In my imports in AppModule I have: 
'IonicModule.forRoot()'
withforRoot() I can pass config to the IonicModule. If I do not pass any config I can also write
'IonicModule'
without forRoot(). This is also equivalent, is it?

Comment: Usually, you need to call `forRoot()`, because it's the way the module content is being exported. Without calling that function, it can happen that you don't import all the necessary exported stuff (`forRoot()` without any parameters may have sensible defaults).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: forRoot/forChild methods usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500895/angular-forroot-forchild-methods-usage)

Answer (score 3):

Only call RouterModule.forRoot() in the root AppRoutingModule (or the AppModule if that's where you register top-level application routes). In any other module, you must call the RouterModule.forChild method to register additional routes.

https://angular.io/guide/router

Here is the difference between RouterModule.forRoot() and RouterModule.forChild()

### RouterModule.forRoot()

1. Declares the router directives
2. Manages our route configuration
3. Register the router service
4. Used once for the application

### RouterModule.forChild()

1. Declares the router directives
2. Manages our route configuration
3. Does not register the router service
4. Used in feature modules