# Angular Component reloading whenever clicking fragment

Tags: angular, routes, fragment, url-routing

I have an static angular component with fragment URL whenever click on the fragment link component every time loading. How to avoid loading angular component each time

```
 http://localhost:53130/sample/url#A
 http://localhost:53130/sample/url#B

<li><a [routerLink]='"."' [fragment]="'A'">A</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]='"."' [fragment]="'B'">B</a></li>
```

Comment: Is this solution for your problem: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3545-enabling-the-second-click-of-a-routerlink-fragment-using-onsameurlnavigation-reload-in-angular-7-1-3.htm

Comment: @SamanthikaRajapaksa i have tried but not working. First time loading the component it's working but when we go to some other route and comeback again it's not working

Comment: Is it possible to post your app-routing.module.ts?

Comment: @Brian const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ParentComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: childrenComponent
  }]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

Comment: did you ever manage to fix this issue? i have to same problem since upgrading from angular 14 to 16. before the functionality worked just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[routerLink]='"."'` with `[routerLink]="[]"`.

Although you don't need `routerLink` if you don't want to navigate to a different route. You could just replace `routerLink` and `fragment` with `href="#A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500895/angular-forroot-forchild-methods-usage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780936/angular-forroot-and-forchild), you may need to re-evaluate your use of `RouterModule.forChild` in your core routing file, **app-routing.module.ts**.

Perhaps you can try editing your **app-routing.modules.ts** file to contain the following:

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  scrollOffset: [0, 64],  
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'ignore',
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

You can toggle `onSameUrlNavigation` to have the value 'ignore' or 'reload'. If you change it to *'ignore'*, does it change the behavior when you click on the fragment link? The above has worked for me.

As the linked articles show, you can rather implement `RouterModule.forChild` in a separate routing file if it contains specific routes you want to use in relation to your base/root.